# Can I use function composition to avoid the "temporary list" in scala?

Tags: scala

On page 64 of fpis 《function programming in scala 》said

```
List(1,2,3,4).map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 3)
```

"each transformation
will produce a temporary list that only ever gets used as input to the next transformation
and is then immediately discarded"

so the compiler or the library can't help to avoid this?

if so,is this haskell code also produce a temporary list?

```
map (*2) (map (+1) [1,2,3])
```

if it is,can I use function composition to avoid this?

```
map ((*2).(+1)) [1,2,3]
```

If I can use function composition to avoid temporary list in haskell,can I use function composition to avoid temporary list in scala?

I know scala use funciton "compose" to compose function:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-function-composition/

so can I write this to avoid temporary list in scala?

```
((map(x:Int=>x+10)) compose (filter(x=>x%2==0)) compose (map(x=>x*3)) (List(1,2,3,4))
```

(IDEA told me I can't)

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to compose map calls, what you need to compose are the lambdas. But that only works if all operations are `map` but since you also have `filter` you can not compose the functions. - What you can do is use laziness in your advantage, just add `.Iterator.` after the list and before the first method call and add a `toList` at the end; that will apply all the steps in one without intermediate collections. Although, you should not care about that unless profiling have show you that you have a bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not supposed to. If you consider map fusion, it nicely works with pure functions:

```scala
List(1, 2, 3).map(_ + 1).map(_ * 10)
// can be fused to
List(1, 2, 3).map(x => (x + 1) * 10)
```

However, Scala is not a purely functional language, nor does it have any notion of purity in it that compiler could track. For example, with side-effects there's a difference in behavior:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map { i => println(i); i + 1 }.map { i => println(i); i * 10 }
// prints 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4

List(1, 2, 3).map { i =>
  println(i)
  val j = i + 1
  println(j)
  j * 10
}
// prints 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4
```

---

Another thing to note is that Scala `List` is a strict collection - if you have a reference to a list, all of its elements are already allocated in memory. Haskell list, on the contrary, is lazy (like most of things in Haskell), so even if temporary "list shell" is created, it's elements are kept unevaluated until needed. That also allows Haskell lists to be infinite (you can write `[1..]` for increasing numbers)

The closest Scala counterpart to Haskell list is `LazyList`, which doesn't evaluate its elements until requested, and then caches them. So doing

```scala
LazyList(1,2,3,4).map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 3)
```

Would allocate intermediate `LazyList` instances, but not calculate/allocate any *elements* in them until they are requested from the final list. `LazyList` is also suitable for infinite collections (`LazyList.from(1)` is analogous to Haskell example above except it's Int).

Here, actually, doing `map` with side effects twice or fusing it by hand will make no difference.

You can switch any collection to be "lazy" by doing `.view`, or just work with iterators by doing `.iterator` - they have largely the same API as any collection, and then go back to a concrete collection by doing `.to(Collection)`, so something like:

```scala
List(1,2,3,4).view.map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 3).to(List)
```

would make a List without any intermediaries. The catch is that it's not necessarily *faster* (though usually is more memory efficient).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid these temporary lists by using views:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/views.html

It's also possible to use function composition to express the function that you asked about:

```
((_: List[Int]).map(_ + 10) andThen (_: List[Int]).filter(_ % 2 == 0) andThen (_: List[Int]).map(_ * 3))(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

But this will not avoid the creation of temporary lists, and due to Scala's limited type inference, it's usually more trouble than it's worth, because you often end up having to annotate types explicitly.

Comment: "it's usually more trouble than it's worth" - It's not worth anything, it just makes no sense whatsoever ;)